# zoom browser IE using javascript without CSS

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, zooming

Sir,

Can you please help me to zoom IE browser with javascript without using CSS.
Because using CSS causes my menu to get misplaced

Thank you for your kind help in advance

Thanks & Regards
Ragesh MK

Answer (score 0):

Try to refer to the example below.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
        function zoom() {
            document.body.style.zoom = "300%" 
        }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="zoom()">
<p>Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

If you get pop up to **Allow Blocked Content** then allow it in Internet Explorer.

[image]